# Gradle dependency management using pom.xml

Tags: maven, gradle

In build.gradle we specify the dependencies as

```
compile group: 'org.apache.pig', name: 'pigunit', version: '0.11.0-cdh4.5.0', transitive: true
```

Running gradle cleanEclipse eclipse sets up the projects(adds the jar to classpath)

However there are only maven dependencies available for some APIs
(I am trying to run jersey 2.x examples bundle from https://jersey.java.net/download.html and it provides only pom.xml)

EDIT:
I know i can specify 
compile group: 'groupId', name: 'artifactId', version: 'version' gradle but doing it manually for all dependencies or writing a program to do so should not be natural gradle way.
Gradle provides a maven plugin http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html.I haven't tried it out but it should be able to do it

Answer (score 1):

Gradle supports Maven dependencies. Just specify the dependencies in the same way as your example:

```
compile group: 'groupId', name: 'artifactId', version: 'version'
```

To lookup the the artifact coordinates, you can use sites like http://search.maven.org

The only thing you have to make sure is to include either your internal Maven repository (if you are in a company which has one) or Maven Central:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

or

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
    }
}
```